# Avoid restarting Jupyter kernel in package develop mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am working on a python package as a developer. The package is stored in a git repo and I use a local branch to debug/fix this package.

I use Jupyter notebooks using pip in edit mode to load my local branch as a package, where I test changes I make.

**I run the following steps:**

1. Load the local package in a develop mode
2. Import the module I want to test
3. Do the test

For instance:

```
! pip install -e Path/To/Local/Package/ # step 1

import local_foo as foo # step 2
foo.print() # step 3
```

After step 3 if the code doesn't behave as expected, I correct my package, **restart the jupyter kernel**, and re-run the 3 previous steps until I get the behavior I want.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to avoid restarting the kernel?

**I tried the following but it doesn't work in this case:**
*IPython autoreload*:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```

and *importlib.reload*:

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(foo)
```

I tried the solution suggested in this article:
https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart

Many thanks!

---

PS: In addition, can some of you can share tips, workflows or experiences using Jupyter notebooks to manage python package development (test,...)

Comment: Could you post an example of the code you tried the `autoreload` extension with? Why does it not work? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue , while importing a custom script in jupyter notebook

Try importing the module as an alias then reloading it

```
import local_foo as foo
from importlib import reload
reload(foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

I hate restarting kernels and sometimes it seems like it is the only option but I have tried this and it worked:

```
import local_foo as foo
from importlib import reload

reload(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to deal with reference issues as packages which are not pure Python may not be easily reloaded using `importlib.reload`.

This may be resolved by removing it from the modules and namespace before reloading it.

```
import foo  # The first import of the package

import sys
import importlib

# Do things with foo

del sys.modules['foo']  # Remove it from the currently loaded modules
del foo  # Remove it's name

importlib.reload(foo)
```

[Joseph Garvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50385/joseph-garvin) writes a very nice function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080151/7195043) which operates similarly and also supports imports of the form `from foo import bar`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoreload`, adding these two lines at the beginning of your Jupyter notebook:

```py
%reload_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
```